# How can I create Dynamic Title in my Windows Phone Application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dynamic, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, title

In my opinion, Title is one of the most important thing for application's popularity and I am developing a multilanguage application, so I want to create a dynamic title to give traditional titles to my application. Could you help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete guide, how to create localized application Title for your Windows Phone 8 apps:
[How to localize an app title for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And here is a nice app, that makes this process much more easier:
[WP8 Localize](http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp8-localize/)